# Changed SATA port, BIOS detects the drive and has it in correct boot order but still can't boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, sata

I recently built a new PC, and for organizational purposes, I moved the graphics card to another PCIex16 slot, which meant that I had to change the SATA ports for my SSD (boot drive) and my HDD. After that, I tried to boot, but I keep getting the message "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media." The BIOS can detect both drives and they are in the correct boot order, so I am not sure why I am getting this message. What can I do to successfully boot after changing the SATA ports?

Comment: Have you changed the boot order? Its likely attempting to boot from your HDD now instead of your SSD.

Comment: The following are shown in the boot options in this order: Windows Boot Manager(P4: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB) -> SATA5: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB -> SATA6: ST2000DM006-2DM164 (HDD). Even if I manually choose to boot from either the boot manager or the hard drive, the boot is unsuccessful.